# Extract rows where a column has null values group by id

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery, window-functions

I have following table in Postgres 11

```
id          type1   type2                         type3                   code     
NCT00160290 Drug    lactulose                     lactulose               A05BA | A06AD
NCT00160290 Drug    plantago ovata                plantago ovata          (null)
NCT00251238 Drug    ginkgo biloba extract         ginkgo biloba extract   (null)
```

I would like to extract all those rows where type3 is not null but code is null but in case any id has code for any type3, I should exclude it.

I am trying following query

```
select distinct * 
from table
where type3 is not null 
  and code is null   --but this will include 'NCT00160290' which has a code
group by id
```

The desired output is:

```
id          type1   type2                         type3                   code     
NCT00251238 Drug    ginkgo biloba extract         ginkgo biloba extract   (null)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `select distinct *` makes no sense. `*` includes the primary key column(s) and thus will never remove any duplicates.

Comment: You say you don't want `'NCT00160290'` in the output, but it is there in your desired results, so your question is rather unclear.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for pointing out.. I corrected it..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.type3 is not null
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from mytable t1
        where t1.id = t.id and t1.code is not null
    )
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `(id, code)`.

Alternatively, you can use window functions:

```
select 
from (
    select t.*, bool_or(code is not null) over(partition by id) has_non_null_code
    from mytable t
) t
where not has_non_null_code
```